# iOS Image upload via AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I've been looking examples for the new AFNetworking 2.0 to upload images.
But I'm hitting wall and couldn't figure out what's wrong with the code.
So this is  the code I used

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];


AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserverurl.com"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL]; 

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:imageData progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
    }
}];
[uploadTask resume];
```

TIA

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I ended up using the multi-part request

```c
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: `appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"image" error:nil]` is not working anymore, I guess. You should use: `[formData appendPartWithFormData:imageData name:@"image"];` ...but still it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: and why do you even bother with fileURl if you're not using it after?

Comment: @raistlin `appendPartWithFileData` worked for me as well. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20190352/1933185

Comment: @raistlin I think you mean "filePath," which indeed does not seem to be used here.

Comment: @ordinaryman09 do u know how to add Header values with an image?

Comment: In my case it worked after add this:  `[formData appendPartWithFileData:img_data name:@"add_file[]" fileName:@"abc.png"mimeType:@"image/png"];`