# AFNewtorking upload photos error after some time over 4G and WIFI

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-2

I have an app that allows users to upload photos. We have experimented problems (upload stops) both 4G and WIFI on some devices on Vodafone carrier. It seems a random error, users can send photos until suddenly no more photos are sent. Here's the method I use to send the photos: (I tried to setup the throttleBandwith at different sizes and delays with no luck. I tried sending packets with a Vodafone device and when the device has consumed all the data transfer, the packets bigger than 2k returns "request body stream exhausted").

Thanks for any suggestion.

```
- (void)postPhotoDataWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters data:(NSData *)data endPoint:(NSString *)endPoint onCompletion:(FetchDataCompletionBlock)completionBlock {

   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

   [self setupAdditionalHeadersToConfiguration:self.session.configuration];

   [self POST:endPoint parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
      NSString *formatedFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo.jpeg"];
      [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:kJSON_USER_PHOTO_FILE fileName:formatedFileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
      [formData throttleBandwidthWithPacketSize:1024 delay:0.01];
   } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
      NSDictionary *data = responseObject;
      completionBlock(data, nil);
   } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
      if ([[[error userInfo] objectForKey:AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey] statusCode] != 200) {
        completionBlock(nil,error);
        NSLog(@"Comunications error");
      }
      completionBlock(nil, error);
   }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this category in this answer:

[solution to "request body stream exhausted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852773/error-when-uploading-photo-with-afnetworking)

hope this help