# Most optimized way to convert image to text

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, post, base64

I am writing an iPhone app that will upload an image to a server, and the server will process it.  I want to know the best way to upload the image.  I know I could use base 64 encoding to convert the image as text and then POST the string, but using only 64 characters does not seem very efficient.  Are there either any better ways to convert an image to text, or even a better way to upload an image than converting to text?

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer I believe.

[iOS Image upload via AFNetworking 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261481/ios-image-upload-via-afnetworking-2-0)

AFNetworking is a third party library that makes web service calls easy.

You can get the library from here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

A good tutorial is here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qjig7ZnH73Y

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.