# resuming upload of file after app crash using nsurlsession

Tags: ios, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I want to upload a file to a server using NSURLSession.

Cases Are:
1. It should resume uploading a file to the server from where it stopped because of app crash.
2. It should handle background upload as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) Library to upload image asynchronously.You can find a brief example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261481/ios-image-upload-via-afnetworking-2-0).

Answer (score 0):

You should use background `NSURLSession`. If your app crashed or user left the app while upload was in progress, with a background `NSURLSession` the upload would continue seamlessly in the background. When the upload is done, your app will be notified of this via the `delegate` (and if your app wasn't alive at the time the download finished, it will be started in a background mode, at which point you can do whatever cleanup you need).

So create `NSURLSessionConfiguration` with `backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier`, and then instantiate a `NSURLSession` with that configuration.

There are a few caveats:

- You cannot use completion handler pattern. You have to use delegate-based implementation.
- You have to implement `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in the app delegate, capturing the `completionHandler` it passes you and also instantiate the background session again. Likewise, in your `NSURLSession` delegate methods, you have to implement `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession`, which will call the saved completion handler.

For more information, see [Background Task Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44) in *URL Session Programming Guide*, see a section of the same name (but different text) in the [NSURLSession class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013435-CH1-SW37), or see the WWDC 2013 [What's New in Foundation Networking](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/705/), where Apple first introduced us to background sessions.